# How to retrieve characters starting from a specific string until last array of characters

Tags: javascript

row1: `10016/Documents/abc.pdf`

row2: `10016-10017/10017/Documents/folder1/folder2/xyz.pdf`

I'm trying to retrieve all the characters starting from /Documents but without the last part (file name)

In row 1, I want to retrieve `/Documents/`

In row 2, I want to retrieve `/Documents/folder1/folder2/`

I tried

```
var temp1 = FullPath.split("/Documents/")[0];

var A_Fpath = temp1.split("/");

A_Fpath = A_Fpath[A_Fpath.length - 1];
```

Comment: is `Documents` constant?

Comment: What does your attempt return?

Comment: yes, Documents is a constant

Comment: my code is returning 10016 and 10016-10017 for temp1

10016 and 10017 for A_Fpath

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex would do the trick:

```
/\/Documents.*\//
/                    start the regex
 \/                  match literally a "/" (the \ is to escape the / reserved character)
   Documents         match literally the word "Documents" (case sensitive
            .*       match 0 or more characters (any characters)
              \/     match literally a "/"
                /    end the regex
   
This works because regex will attempt to match the longest possible string
of characters that match the regex.
```

```js
const row1 = "10016/Documents/abc.pdf";
const row2 = "10016-10017/10017/Documents/folder1/folder2/xyz.pdf";

const regex = /\/Documents.*\//;

const val1 = row1.match(regex)[0];
const val2 = row2.match(regex)[0];

console.log(val1);
console.log(val2);
```

Here's a [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wdnOVy/1) link to test it out and see more info about this specific regex.

Comment: thanks, this may not work if filename has "Documents" ?

Comment: This works even if the filename is/has "Documents" as it specifically looks for the `"/"` after the word "Documents", and a filename cannot have a `"/"`... look at the Regex101 link from my answer

Answer (score 0):

If javascript had a grown-up regular expression engine, one could use a *positive, non-capturing lookahead group* to determine when to stop.

Since javascript lacks that, the simple, clearer, and more efficient way is to not use a regular expression at all. The algorithm is simple:

- Find the [first/leftmost] `/Documents` in the source text, then
- Find the last/rightmost occurrence of `/` in the source text
- Deal with the two special cases where:

  - The source string doesn't contain `/Documents` at all, and
  - The rightmost `/` is the `/` in `/Documents`
- Failing a special case as noted above, return the desired substring
  extending from `/Documents` up to and including the last `/`

Like this:

```js
function getInterestingBitsFrom(path) {
  const i   = path.indexOf('/Documents');
  const j   = path.lastIndexOf('/');
  const val = i < 0   ? undefined     // no '/Documents' in string
            : i === j ? path.slice(i) // last '/' in string is the '/' in '/Documents'             
            : path.slice(i, j+1)      // '/Documents/' or '/Documents/.../'
            ;

  return retVal;  
}
```

This also has the laudatory benefit of being easy to understand for someone who has to figure out what you were trying to accomplish.